# How to match exponents that can be 0?

Tags: replacement

I want to do some transformation of the following expression

```
Inactive[Integrate][E^(-((m x^k)/k!)), {x, 0, y}] + 
 Inactive[Integrate][E^(-((m x^k)/k!)) x^2, {x, 0, y}] + 
 Inactive[Integrate][1/3 E^(-((m x^k)/k!)) m x^3, {x, 0, y}]
```

and I need to have the exponent of `m` and `x` in each integral to do this. As you can see, these exponents can be `0` or `1` sometimes. So I cannot simply use `m^a_. x^b_.` to find the exponents.

One solution is to use `Exponent` to subtract the exponents and check what the exponents are. But I wonder if this is the easiest way to do it.

Right now I just use 3 different rules to deal with it

```
intrule={Inactive[Integrate][(c_. ) E^(-((m x_^k)/k!)) m^a_. x_^b_.,{x_,0,y}]->c (k!)^((b+1)/k)/k m^(a-((b+1)/k)) Inactive[Gamma][(b+1)/k,0,(m y^k)/k!] ,
Inactive[Integrate][(c_. ) E^(-((m x_^k)/k!)) x_^b_.,{x_,0,y}]->c (k!)^((b+1)/k)/k m^(0-((b+1)/k)) Inactive[Gamma][(b+1)/k,0,(m y^k)/k!],
Inactive[Integrate][(c_. ) (E^(-((m x_^k)/k!))) ,{x_,0,y}]->c (k!)^((0+1)/k)/k m^(0-((0+1)/k)) Inactive[Gamma][(0+1)/k,0,(m y^k)/k!]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a transformation, e.g. in terms of a `Rule`? If the expressions need special treatment when an exponent is 0, then I find it reasonable to provide Mathematica with a `Rule` to provide this special treatment, rather than expect Mathematica to figure this out without the user telling it how to do it...